# ROS2 Error: Modulenotfounderror: No module named 'laser_geometry'

Tags: python, ros2, nvidia-jetson-nano

```
# ROS NODE import
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

# Lidar Process(Point cloud)
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from laser_geometry import LaserProjection
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
```

In ROS2 Foxy version, although the laser-geometry package is installed, when running a Python script from a custom package, it is not recognized.

How can i fix it?

1. reinstall ros-foxy-laser-geometry
2. there's laser_geometry.py script in ros humble version, but not in ros foxy version. But i have to use laser_geometry on ros foxy because my cpu 'jetson nano' is only compatible with foxy

Answer (score 0):

Try to build from source
https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_geometry/tree/ros2

And check for dependency

```
sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-sensor-msgs-py
```